# gcp terraform deadlettering gives error message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, service-accounts

I am deploying a subscription to gcp using terraform which includes dead letter.  Once deployed I see the following warning

[image]

However when I look at hte service accounts in my project I do not see a pub/sub service account specific to the project

As per the documentation here https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push it says the service account should be something like `{PROJECT_NUMBER}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com` however I do not see such a service account, all I see are

[image]

Comment: Check whether SA is at MENU>PUBSUB>SUB NAME>3 dots>View permissions

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#setting_up_for_push_authentication) you are following:

> If you use the Cloud Console to set up the subscription for push
> authentication or you use a project created after April 8, 2021, the
> role is granted automatically as part of the Pub/Sub service agent
> role. Otherwise, you must explicitly grant the role to the account.

This fix is only a possibility since I cannot verify if your project has been created prior April 8. Having that cleared, you can either use the template below to add the role in IAM via Cloud shell:

```
PUBSUB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT="service-${PROJECT_NUMBER}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_ID} \
 --member="serviceAccount:${PUBSUB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}"\
 --role='roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator'
```

Or you can do it via console by following the steps below:

1. Go to Menu > IAM
2. Click Add
3. Input in new members:

> service-{PROJECT_NUMBER}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com

```
Note: PROJECT_NUMBER can be seen from Menu > Home > Project Info > Project Number
```

4. Under Role choose

> Service Account Token Creator

5. Click Save

After doing so, the service account should now appear on IAM > Roles if 'Include Google-provided role grants' is checked.